# Inverse image of $[0,1/2]$ for $f(x)=\sin(x)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, trigonometry, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Describe the set: $$f^{-1}\bigg(\Big[0,\frac{1}{2}\Big]\bigg).$$ My answer is $$f^{-1}([0,1])=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \Big[2n\pi,(2n+\frac{1}{6})\pi\Big]\cup\Big[(2n+\frac{5}{6})\pi,(2n+1)\pi\Big].$$

I first solved $\sin(x)=1/2$ and then used the graph to get to my answer.

[image]

I was wondering if my answer is correct.

Comment: Your answer is ok, but looking at the graph is no prove...

Comment: @sigmabe I used the graph to help me find the result. But what do you suggest to do in order to prove it?

Comment: you can use that sin is continuous and on some intervalls monotonous.